# PhoneGap (2.4) plugin error: 'class not found'

Tags: java, android, cordova

I tried to convert a simple Java class to a PhoneGap plugin, but I can't load it, I have out of ideas now.

Here is the class:
https://gist.github.com/kowdermeister/5013353

I have added the following to /res/xml/config/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="MediaPlayerStateWrapper" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.MediaPlayerStateWrapper"/>
```

and here is the JS that tries to load an MP3

```
cordova.exec( function () {
    // Success
    cordova.exec(function(){ alert('playing') }, function () {
        // Failed to start
    },'MediaPlayerStateWrapper', 'play');
}, function (e) {
    alert(e)
}, 'MediaPlayerStateWrapper','setDataSource', ['http://...']);
```

My environment is:

Eclipse (ADT)

Target: Android 4.2

PhoneGap SDK: cordova-2.4.0rc1.js

Comment: What is the error you see in "adb logcat"?

Comment: Application: com.clouddeck
Tag: System.out
Text: "Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.pluguins.MediaPlayerStateWrapper"

(I knew I forgot something to mention)

Comment: pluguins is a mistype of course

Comment: Sorry does that mean you mistyped it in the comment or in your config.xml cause that'd cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I mistyped it here, logcat can't copy text :( The path is correct in logcat.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. It if is not a path issue, I guess the class design is missing something. Would you take a look at it? I'm just jumped into Java for the sake of PhoneGap.

Comment: ...or if you know a way (another plugin) to access the buffered state of a remote MP3 then I'd be equally happy.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my...

I've found the problem. I tried to load manually my plugin into the main android onCreate method and Eclipse warned me that I can't access my Class's methods, because its constructur is not public. It was not set at all, so after changing it to public it could be loaded.

It still doesn't play a sound, but this is different story now :)